# Paging get all keys on riak with Java Api

Tags: riak

we are currently testing out Riak, we have in Riak a huge bucket with millions of keys and I need to query all the keys and save them in a file.
We are using Java as the API.

Is there any way to get the result of the query paged?

Answer (score 1):

Listing millions of keys in Riak is [not recommended in production environments](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/protocol-buffers/list-keys/) as it is a very expensive operation. If you still need to do it, it is best to use the list keys function as this allows Riak to stream results back to the client and will work for any backend.

While it is possible to perform paging for secondary index queries if you are using LevelDB or the memory backend in version 1.4 onwards, this requires sorting on the server side and is therefore not recommended for such large result sets.

Comment: I need to load all keys (by demand) to a cache file, I know this is not a recommended production solution, is there another solution?

Comment: I've seen suggestions to use the secondary index $key, this should allow me to use the continuation parameter. I cannot find how to use this in Java

Comment: If you absolutely need to list all the keys, use a streaming key listing. If you use LevelDB this will use the internal indexes behind the scenes. Trying to use pagination will put significantly more load on the cluster than a key listing given the large number of keys you expect to return. I also don't think pagination is possible for the special $key and $bucket indexes.